# Calculate the Energy Consumption for a day based on series of Kw

Tags: energy, consumption

I am not from a electric background person. For this project, I need to calculate the total energy consumption (kwH) for a device.

In this system, the reading of kW for each device is store in the database for each minute. My question is, how do i calculate the total energy consumption (kwH) for a day based on series of kW store every minute.

Below is the example of the value of the database.

[The value inside the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrEE1.png)

The value is for the whole day. For this questioning purpose, I only took the 30 minute example.

All kind of help will be appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

@ameruddin I am not sure this will help but I know the simple formula for convertion of `kw -> kwh` is `kWh = kW × hr`

1 kilowatt per minute = 60 kilowatts / hour

also 1 kilo watt minute (kWmin) = 0.017 kilowatt hours (kWh)

I think that helps

Thanks

Comment: by meaning that, i need to convert the every minute kw to kwh ?

Comment: if you do that calculation every minute you will get result accurately
else you can do take the average of the power every hour so that you will get average of the power in kwh format
or else you can do like add another column in DB which will convert the kw in to kwh (i.e 0.017 * powerkw) at the end of the day sum that column hence you will get kwh as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

In other words, what you need to do is to integrate the kW readings over the period of measurement. You just need to multiply each kW readings by its (assumed) duration (1 minute in this case), add them, and divide by 60 to convert minutes to hours. For an example, kWh for the first 3 minutes would be (6.064*1+6.032*1+6.064*1)/60
Thank you.